# Can not link VS Fortran to MKL with setting MKL lib to 'parallel'

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

I am using VS community 2013 and parallel studio 2015 release. Now I want to use the code examples to check the MKL package. I have set the project `<fortran<lib mkl` to parallel, but it continues shows the error:

> can not open include file "fftw_f77".

The program is as follows.

```
 PROGRAM COMPLEX_1D_DOUBLE_EX2

      INCLUDE 'fftw_f77.i'
      INCLUDE 'mkl_fftw_examples.fi'

      INTEGER N,I
      PARAMETER (N=10)
      INTEGER*8 MY_PLAN

      COMPLEX*16 IN(N),OUT(N),EXP_X(N)
      REAL*8 ERR,SCALE

!
!     Initialize IN and copy to expected EXP_X
!
      PRINT *, 'Initialize data array'
      CALL INIT_COMPLEX_VECTOR_Z(IN,N)
      DO I=1,N
       EXP_X(I)=IN(I)
      END DO

!
!     Create FFTW plan for 1D forward transform
!
      PRINT *, 'Create FFTW plan for 1D forward transform'
      CALL FFTW_F77_CREATE_PLAN(MY_PLAN,N,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE)

!
!     Compute Forward
!
      PRINT *, 'Compute Forward'
      CALL FFTW_F77_ONE(MY_PLAN,IN,OUT)

      do I=1,N
          print *, 'Forward: OUT(', I, ') = ', OUT(I)
      end do

!
!     Destroy FFTW plan
!
      PRINT *, 'Destroy FFTW plan'
      CALL FFTW_F77_DESTROY_PLAN(MY_PLAN)

!
!     Create FFTW plan for 1D backward transform
!
      PRINT *, 'Create FFTW plan for 1D backward transform'
      CALL FFTW_F77_CREATE_PLAN(MY_PLAN,N,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE)

!
!     Compute Backward
!
      PRINT *, 'Compute Backward'
      CALL FFTW_F77_ONE(MY_PLAN,OUT,IN)

      do I=1,N
          print *, 'Backward: IN(', I, ') = ', IN(I)
      end do

!
!     Destroy FFTW plan
!
      PRINT *, 'Destroy FFTW plan'
      CALL FFTW_F77_DESTROY_PLAN(MY_PLAN)

!
!     Scale result. FFTW can't do this itself.
!
      PRINT *, 'Scale result by 1/N'
      SCALE=1.0D0/N
      DO I=1,N
       IN(I)=SCALE*IN(I)
      END DO

!
!     Check results
!
      PRINT *, 'Check results'
      CALL CHECK_RESULT_Z(IN,EXP_X,N,ERR)
      PRINT *, 'Accuracy=',ERR
      IF (ERR .GT. MAX_DOUBLE_ERR) THEN
       PRINT *, 'TEST FAILED'
       STOP 1
      END IF
      PRINT *, 'TEST PASSED'

      PRINT *, 'END OF TEST'

      END PROGRAM
```

the code should be correct as it is from the official website as examples. errors are from the environment setting or path setting, but I do not know how to set it. I tried the the steps below:

1. Go to Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>Intel Performance Libraries.
2. Change the Use MKL property setting by selecting Parallel, Sequential, or Cluster as appropriate.

but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the line

```
INCLUDE 'fftw_f77.i'
```

by

```
INCLUDE 'fftw/fftw_f77.i'
```

Comment: now it shows error: error #5102: Cannot open include file 'mkl_fftw_examples.fi'

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. They are useless for future visitors.